# Scraping Medium's clap data without Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape clap data from medium [let's say this is the link](https://medium.com/@xdxxxx4713/basic-settings-of-nginx-aeace532534f). When I inspect it looks like in this photo.

[image: webScraper medium button]

My code looks like this :

```
URL = "https://medium.com/@xdxxxx4713/basic-settings-of-nginx-aeace532534f"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

There's only -- in the output where there should be the value of the clap. If it's possible how can I scrape the clap value without using Selenium? After getting the value with HTML request "requests.get(URL)" I can do the rest. The html request returns empty at where the clap value should be.

[image: Output]

- I tried to use urllib library but I have Non-ASCII characters on my links
- I tried using BeautifulSoup's findChildren library.
- I tried using BeautifulSoup's descendants traverse algorithm.

Comment: The value you’re after is painted into the DOM by a JavaScript method. Neither `requests` nor `BeautifulSoup` is capable of executing or interpreting such JavaScript code. Selenium would be an easy way to open this URL and extract the value post-JavaScript execution, but in the absence of that being a possibility, have you attempted to inspect any network requests that are going out from the target page for this data and attempting to model *them* in `requests`? Where did that lead you?

Comment: On second pass, it looks like [someone’s already taken a pass at doing this in Python with `requests`](https://github.com/FrenchTechLead/medium-stats-api), have you considered refactoring and re-using their code for your purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @esqew mentioned on commands. There's an [API](https://github.com/FrenchTechLead/medium-stats-api) for that but It didn't work for me. But I was inspired by the API code. Here's my code :

```
    aditionalPage = requests.get(pages).content.decode("utf-8")
    claps = aditionalPage.split("clapCount\":")[1]
    endIndex = claps.index(",")
    claps = int(claps[0:endIndex])
```

Comment: So is the question answered now?

Comment: Yes @AntonyHatchkins

Comment: You can accept it then (use the tick mark next to the correct answer).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, try the code below:

```
import requests

data = [{"operationName":"ClapCountQuery","variables":{"postId":"aeace532534f"},"query":"query ClapCountQuery($postId: ID!) {\n  postResult(id: $postId) {\n    __typename\n    ... on Post {\n      id\n      clapCount\n      __typename\n    }\n  }\n}\n"}]
r = requests.post('https://medium.com/_/graphql', json=data)
print(r.json()[0]['data']['postResult']['clapCount'])
```

This will return:

```
4
```